# How to edit INI file value in Powershell?

Tags: powershell, ini

I have an INI file:

```
 [Name]
    Female = 10
    Male = 30

    [Class]
    Kids = 2
    Adult = 10
```

I want to change the value of each section. Give me idea please.

I tried this code:

```
function Set-OrAddIniValue
{
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath,
        [hashtable]$keyValueList
    )

    $content = Get-Content $FilePath

    $keyValueList.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($content -match "^$($_.Key)=")
        {
            $content= $content -replace "^$($_.Key)=(.*)", "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
        }
        else
        {
            $content += "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
        }
    }

    $content | Set-Content $FilePath
}
```

this is the code

Comment: What have you tried? Have any work to show? What part exactly are you stuck at? Stack Overflow is not a code writing service. If you need help learning how to code or troubleshoot something then this is the place for you.

Comment: The main problem I see is that your `-match` and `-replace` regexes start with the `^` character. Given the example of an INI file in this post, the first character on a line could be a space. That will make all of your matches and replacements fail. There are also spaces around your `=` character that you are also not accounting for.

Comment: What exactly do you want to edit? The `Section`s or the `Values` inside these sections? Maybe better if you use a module dedicated to handle INI files like for instance [PsIni](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/PsIni/2.0.3)

Answer (score 0):

You would do so:

```
$ini = Get-IniContent "<pathToYourIniFile>"
$ini["<yourSection>"]["<yourKey>"] = "<yourValue>"
$ini | out-inifile -FilePath "<pathToYourIniFile>"
```

Comment: Where is the problem?

Comment: I tried this:

`$input_file = Get-Content "C:\Users\test.ini"
 $input_file["Name"]["Female"]="30" 
 $input_file | Out-IniFile -Force -FilePath "C:\Users\test.ini"`

I used -Force because I want to overwrite the previous file. But This code return me an error: `Cannot index into a null array.`

Answer (score 0):

If you updated your code to the following, it will be more successful:

```
function Set-OrAddIniValue
{
    Param(
        [string]$FilePath,
        [hashtable]$keyValueList
    )

    $content = Get-Content $FilePath
    $keyValueList.GetEnumerator() | ForEach-Object {
        if ($content -match "$($_.Key)\s*=")
        {
            $content= $content -replace "$($_.Key)\s*=(.*)", "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
        }
        else
        {
            $content += "$($_.Key)=$($_.Value)"
        }
    }

    $content | Set-Content $FilePath
}
```

One problem will be if you add extra key/value pairs, they will all be added to the last section. In other words, the code is not section-aware.

Comment: But I still cant sucess with this code. I try this code executed from cmd like this:
`script.ps1 -FilePath -keyValueList Name.Female=200`

Comment: The `-keyValueList` parameter expects a hashtable type to be passed to it. So you need to do something like this `-keyValueList @{"Female"=200}`. This code alone is not section-aware. You will need additional code for that.